# Expo Notification

Tags: android, notifications, expo

I am using expo notification for my app and it works fine on ios but it doesn't work on android. the way i am doing the notification is I am getting the key by the below code

```
const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
          Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
        );
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;

        // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
        // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
          // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
          // install, so this will only ask on iOS
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
          finalStatus = status;
        }

        // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
          return;
        }

        // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
        let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
        alert(token)
```

then saving the token in the server and send the notification as the following:

send Post Method
https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send

```
{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[HOKJqEF5FdGLRO7s-Kg4Ns]",
  "title":"Test",
  "body": "Test"
}
```

do I have to use firebase FCM to get it work in Android ?

Answer (score 1):

According to expo [tutorial](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications#2-call-expos-push-api-with-the) there's no need for FCM to use Expo push notification service on android, unless you want to create APK for release.

I already created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@iteacode_dev/expo-push-notif-sample) for comparison, you may need real device that installed expo to obtain the push token. You should be receive response like below when call `https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send` :

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "a0c9af62-5b56-449e-aaea-51bee782dd3d",
        "status": "ok"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to release your app in Google Play Store - which is the whole point. In the expo App it also uses FCM under the hood.

The [expo push notification documentation page](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/) is not super clear in mentioning that, there are few steps needed for push notification to work in a standalone android/ios app. Although it mentions in the documentation as "Next Steps" at the bottom of the page, but from the first paragraph it is not certainly clear that they are distinguishing expo app notification from standalone android/ios app notification. Rather it felt that Expo takes care of all the things as if no more steps require for standalone apps. It is certainly right only for Expo app. However, when we land into the [Next Steps](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/) page, we find the most important information in the "Credentials" section.

So this is how it works for Android Stand alone app (which I have done). We need to setup our own Firebase project as it says here [Using FCM for Push Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/). If you are using Expo server to send Push notification, make sure to follow the steps "Upload Server Credentials". You will see the FCM Server Key added in your Expo Credentials.

It should not take too much of a time but for me it took 1 hour or so to setup these extra steps as I was learning these, for the first time.